# click() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$j('#carousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: true,
    scroll: 1,
    auto: 2,
    wrap: 'last',
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
});
$j('div#slideshow-carousel a img').css({
    'opacity': '0.5'
});
$j('div#slideshow-carousel a img:first').css({
    'opacity': '1.0'
});
$j('div#slideshow-carousel li a').hover(
function () {
    if (!$j(this).has('span').length) {
        $j('div#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({
            'opacity': '0.5'
        });
        $j(this).stop(true, true).children('img').css({
            'opacity': '1.0'
        });
    }
}, function () {
    $j('div#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({
        'opacity': '0.5'
    });
    $j('div#slideshow-carousel li a').each(function () {
        if ($j(this).has('span').length) $j(this).children('img').css({
            'opacity': '1.0'
        });
    });
}).click(function () {
    $j('div#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active');
    $j('div#slideshow-main li.' + $j(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

This simple carousel script works perfectly except the click part; nothing happens on clicking the thumbnails, they should be applied the 'active' class.

Comment: Bracket overflow. What is `.click()` chained to?

Comment: $j('div#slideshow-carousel li a') no ?

Comment: Are you **sure** the click isn't happening? Or could it be that your CSS isn't doing what you expect? That's the first thing to check, walk through it with a debugger.

Comment: Yes, I don't see the 'active' class being applied to any of the li's. Using Firebug.

Comment: @Nimbuz: That's not the same thing at all. First figure out whether the `click` works (by putting a breakpoint, whatever). If not, you know you're looking for a problem with `click`. But if `click` works, you're looking at a problem in the code *within* your click handler. And in fact, I think that's exactly it (see my answer).

Comment: **Off-topic**: Regarding the three lines about 3/4ths of the way down, starting with `if ($j(this).has('span').length) $j(this).children('img').css({` -- can I just say, \*\*shudder\*\*. That just looks like a maintenance error waiting to happen. Braces (`{}`) are not evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using `slideshow-main` where you mean `slideshow-carousel`, e.g. this:

```
}).click(function () {
    $j('div#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active');
    $j('div#slideshow-main li.' + $j(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

should be:

```
}).click(function () {
    $j('div#slideshow-carousel li').removeClass('active');
    $j('div#slideshow-carousel li.' + $j(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Seems to work, anyway: http://jsbin.com/aliqi3